# How to place components in smartgwt inside nested layouts

Tags: java, gwt, web, smartgwt

I've got about 20 components that are placed in forms and layouts (horizontal and vertical).
Its structure like the html table with something like colspan and rowspan.

Outer grid is authorizing but layouts and components inside main layout don't react to
setHeight, setWidth, setColWidths properly. Some nested components don't react, some does...

How to place components in smartgwt properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the problem but I had layout issues when I first started using smartgwt as well. It turned out that I needed to set my inner components widths and/or heights to "*" this caused my inner components to "snap" to any coordinates supplied by its container.